config watchdog.net for ocelot api gateway
i want to config watchdog.net for ocelot API gateway
but when i login to dashboard watchdog and refresh for load data from database watchdog.net i had this error:

and this is my program.cs
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

//....
builder.Services.AddWatchDogServices();

var app = builder.Build();

//....
app.UseWatchDogExceptionLogger();
app.UseWatchDog(opt =>
{
    opt.WatchPageUsername = "admin";
    opt.WatchPagePassword = "admin";
});
await app.UseOcelot();

await app.RunAsync();


Ocelot registers a load of services after calling service.AddOcelot() method so it is possible to encounter conflict or error.
To overcome this kind of problem you can use service.AddOcelotUsingBuilder().
This method has two parameters, in the first parameter it takes Configuration and in the second one takes IMvcCoreBuilder and in this parameter you can register any kind of services that you might need in your own project.
builder.Services.AddOcelotUsingBuilder(builder.Configuration, (builder, assembly) =>
{
    builder.AddApiExplorer(); 
    builder.AddAuthorization(); 
    return builder;
}) 

